# Memory leak till crash due to HttpRequest

Tags: dart

I played with HttpRequest and realized that the memory is not cleaned up after any request.
After some time the running tab within Chrome will crash.

Here is some testing code. Put a large sized file into the 'web' directory and set the URL in the code accordingly.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  const PATH = "http://127.0.0.1:3030/PATH_TO_FILE";
  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds:10), (Timer it)=>getString(PATH));
}

void getString( String url){
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then((String data){
  });
}
```

Just rechecked, memory leak still exists:

- Current version: 24275
- Used duration: 30 seconds
- Used file: chromium\chrome.dll.pdb copied into web directory of current project
- Tried under Windows 64bit as well as Linux 64bit

The memory leak exists only in Dartium. When I compile the code to JS and run it in Firefox, the memory usage goes up to 3.5 GB and stays there.

Is this really a bug or did I something wrong?

Comment: I made a rather large edit to your post, removing several functions that are never called and making the lines all fit.  As far as I can tell, this captures everything you meant to share...

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with Dartium launch or JS launch (Firefox).

Comment: I rechecked the code and added some additional infos in my post.

Comment: Did you try in Dartium or what? I've seen lots of crashes in Dartium for a wide variety of reasons. Dartium shouldn't be considered a stable browser to use, only for dev.

Comment: Memory leak occurs in Firefox Browser with compiled JS-Code as well.

Comment: @AlexR. Are you sure? Will Firefox crash?

Comment: I checked again: No crash in Firefox. The memory usage increases up to 3.5 GB and stays there. So it seems, that we have "just" a Dartium bug here. I added it to the question accordingly.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so you should consider [filing a bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry).

Answer (score 0):

There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964610/dart-httprequest-polling), suggesting a memory leak in HttpRequest; however I'm not able to find anything in the Dart issue tracker. If you think this might be a real memory leak, it might be worth [raising a bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue but is is closed.
There was an announced change recently that requires to close the request explicitly otherwise it stays open for 15 seconds (default value).

see the discussion at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20833 for more details.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 9090).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      var client = new HttpClient();
      client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")
          .then((req) => req.close())
          .then((resp) => resp.drain())
          .whenComplete(() {
            client.close();
            request.response.close();
          });
    });
  });
}
```

In code like this having a global shared HttpClient instance is the right thing to do as that will handle sharing persistent connections.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 9090).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      var client = new HttpClient();
      client.getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")
          .then((req) => req.close())
          .then((resp) => resp.drain())
          .whenComplete(() => request.response.close());
    });
  });
}
```