# Dart HttpRequest polling

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dartium

I have a web app that have a Timer that fires a poll to get data every 3 seconds. It works fine for about 2.5 minutes then Chromium crashes.

My request Dart looks like this

```dart
HttpRequest.getString('data/get_load_history_recent.json')
  .then((e) => _recentHistoryResponse(e))
  .catchError((e) => _recentHistoryError(e));
```

Can you think of any reasons why this would happen? I assume it's a memory leak...

**Edit:**
Here is my `_recentHistoryResponse()`

```dart
void _recentHistoryResponse(String data)
{
  Map obj = JSON.decode(data);
  if(obj['status'] == 'success')
  {
    List processes = obj['data']['processes'];
    List newItems = new List();

    List oldIdsArray = new List();

    int length = appDataDic.load_history_list.length;
    for(HistoryDataVO oldVO in appDataDic.load_history_list)
    {
      oldIdsArray.add(oldVO.loadID);
    }

    for(Map process in processes)
    {
      HistoryDataVO dataVO = new HistoryDataVO(); 
      dataVO.loadID = process['loadID'];
      dataVO.time = process['time'];
      dataVO.loadType = process['loadType'];
      dataVO.fileName = process['fileName'];
      dataVO.label = process['label'];
      dataVO.description = process['description'];
      dataVO.count = process['count'];
      dataVO.progress = process['progress'];
      dataVO.loadTask = process['loadTask'];

      // Check if the item is currently in the list
      if(length >= 1)
      {
        if(!LoadHistoryHelper.exists(oldIdsArray, dataVO.loadID))
        {
          dataVO.isNew = true;
        }
      }

      newItems.add(dataVO);
    }

    appDataDic.load_history_list.clear();
    appDataDic.load_history_list.addAll(newItems);

  }
}
```

I have commented out the exists check `!LoadHistoryHelper.exists(oldIdsArray, dataVO.loadID))` (because this seemed like the obvious place) but it the VM still crashes.

Also, I have taken this same code and put it into an isolated app with the only real difference in the poll check is `appDataDic.load_history_list` is just an `@observable List`, not an `ObservableList`.

**Edit 2 :**
Ok, so I have discovered that `Map obj = JSON.decode(data);` causes the crash. I was reading in a Javascript forum that timeouts cause the memory to not be released (I had never thought of this but it makes sense), is this true? Can any one think of a better way to do this? Can I directly call the garbage collection? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Could you post your `_recentHistoryResponse()`? If there is a leak, this is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Hey there, I have updated this now

Answer (score 0):

There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393761/memory-leak-till-crash-due-to-httprequest), suggesting a memory leak in HttpRequest; however I'm not able to find anything in the Dart issue tracker. If you think this might be a real memory leak, it might be worth [raising a bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry).